# How do I share my Database diagram to my friend?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I designed one database diagram, I want to share this diagram to some one else.
i had tried right click on db diagram ( selected copy diagram to clipboard) Unfortunately my system has windows -7 OS clip board doesn't support for windows -7 Please can you give your valuable suggestions to me!
thanks for advance .

Comment: So you're saying you get an error message when you right-click and choose "Copy to Clipboard"?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the most recent version of SSMS. It retains full backwards compatibility with older database versions, so if you open a diagram there it should copy to the clipboard fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why clipboard not working but a screenshot is a possible alternative. CTRL-ALT-PRTSCRN and then paste it into email or image program

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

open the diagram
go to the printing options and print it to a file format, instead of a printer. 
you should be able to share that file with your friend

Regards